# MVC for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i have downloaded MVC 2.0 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en)... but it gives me an error that ***MVC 2.0 requires VS 2008 SP1...*** which i have already installed...

so i am having trouble here installing MVC...

plz help here...

Comment: The key there.. is SP!.  Did you install SP1 seperately?

Comment: hmmmm.. thnx... now as i installed SP1 separately... i don't have any options of MVC project while creating an ASP.net project... why is that..?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Visual Studio do you use? It is included in 2010.

If you want it for 2008 and below, you can download it from:

http://www.asp.net/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the [SP1 of VS2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en) installed. In fact, this service pack also adds quite a lot of functionality; it doesn't just fix bugs.

Comment: now as i installed SP1 separately... i don't have any options of MVC project while creating an ASP.net project... why is that..?

Comment: After VS2008 SP1, did you install ASP.NET MVC 2 for VS2008? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C9BA1FE1-3BA8-439A-9E21-DEF90A8615A9&displaylang=en (note that you have to restart VS.NET after the install).

Answer (score 0):

You can download web platform installer [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/11/asp-net-mvc-2-released.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the downloads [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/11/asp-net-mvc-2-released.aspx).